# Pyautogui types a space when trying to press enter

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

```
import time
import pyautogui
import random
from pynput import keyboard

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

phrases = ["Hello, world!", "another phrase"]

while True:
    phrase = random.choice(phrases)
    pyautogui.press("/")
    pyautogui.write(phrase, 0.1)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(10)
```

When I run this code, it types the random phrases but when i want it to press enter, it just presses space

Comment: I've read that `pyautogui.write('\n')` does the same thing, you could try that maybe? Also just to verify, `pyautogui.press("enter")` enters a space, by itself, even without the other code?

Comment: You might want to report this as a bug also, documentation says this should work. https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the issue might be related to the `pyautogui.write()` function. Instead of using `pyautogui.write(phrase, 0.1)`, you can use `pyautogui.typewrite(phrase, interval=0.1)` to ensure the entire phrase is typed correctly.

```py
import time
import pyautogui
import random
from pynput import keyboard

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

phrases = ["Hello, world!", "another phrase"]

while True:
    phrase = random.choice(phrases)
    pyautogui.press("/")
    pyautogui.typewrite(phrase, interval=0.1)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I noticed that when I checked the owner code, it didn't provide me with an `enter` option. However, when I used the `typewrite` function instead, it worked perfectly. By the way, the language you referred to as **ChatGPT** is actually called **Markdown language**, just a friendly clarification, bro ;)